# How can you make a flutter widget extend beyond its parent widget

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, layout

How can you make a widget have a slight extension beyond the edge of its parent like this,
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePZqq.png)

The horizontal listview extends beyond the container it is in

Comment: use `customScrollView`, and `stack` for background images

Answer (score 2):

Using Stack widget 
you can find the documentation here 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html